# How to set value of a object inside an Array in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

In my ember application, I have an array of objects. I need to manipulate some object inside the array.

eg: Array: `[{a:1}]` then I need to change a to 2.

```
someArray: [{a: 1}],
didInsertElement() {
     var self = this;
     this.$('.some-element').on('scroll',function() {
         self.get('someArray')[0]['a'] = 2; // HOW TO DO THIS ?
     });
}
```

Also, I need the changes to be reflected in the view as well.

Note: Ember version 1.13

Comment: What is i, items and index? You want to choose object from array based on what?

Comment: it would be something like `self.get('someArray').objectAt(i).set('item', newvalue)`. BUT where should `i` come from?

Comment: Don't use jQuery events in Ember. Ember provides perfectly good, native ways to handle events.

Comment: @DanielKmak  : I just updated the question. Sorry, I had it cut out from my existing code so I missed out on a few.

Comment: @torazaburo : I could not find any specific event in Ember for scroll. Please do let me know if there is some event I have missed out.

Comment: @torazaburo : I have updated the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var temp = self.get('someArray').objectAt(0);
Ember.set(temp, "a", 2);
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

```
Ember.set(this.get('array').objectAt(index),'prop',value)
```

Comment: Exactly Same as accepted. just the one line. I am thinking what I had in mind when I answered it :). But it is the same

Comment: Why have you added the same answer 1 year after the original?

Answer (score 0):

You can set each Object properties, based on index or each Object, By using forEach iteration.

```
someArray: [],
didInsertElement() {
  var self = this;
  this.$('.some-element').on('scroll',function() {
    //You can add new properties and set properties as follows by iteration
    self.get('someArray').forEach(function(item/*, index*/) {

      var emberObject = Ember.Object.create(item);
      //based on index also you can do
      //if (index === 0) { emberObject.set('newProperty', 'newValue'); }

      emberObject.set('newProperty', 'newValue');            
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
someArray: [],
didInsertElement() {
     this.$('.some-element').on('scroll',function() {
         this.get('someArray').objectAt(i).set('item', items[index]);
     });
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you explain why ?